# AngularJS: Bind angular service property to scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

### Scenario

- I have a service `UserService` that maintains the (boolean) `sessionStatus` of the user.
- The view conditionally shows [LOGOUT] on `ng-show=sessionStatus` (i.e. if not logged in (false), no show).
- `sessionStatus` of `ViewController` should therefore always match that of `UserService` ... right?
- If you click [LOGOUT] when it's visible, it does some loggy outty things, `sessionStatus` value changes, and view should update with new outcome of `ng-show...`.

### Problem

1. Currently, clicking logout does not seem to update var UserService.sessionStatus?
2. How do I keep $scope.sessionStatus updated when UserService.logout() occurs and changes UserService.sessionStatus?

   - How do I map the changing $scope to ng-show?

### Files

#### View

```
    <a ng-show="sessionStatus" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a>
```

#### ViewController

```
    app.controller('AppController', function($scope, $interval, $http, UserService) {
      $scope.logout = function() { UserService.logout(); }

      // This ain't working
      $scope.$watch(UserService.sessionStatus, function() {
          $scope.sessionStatus = UserService.sessionStatus;
      });
    });
```

#### UserService

NB: appUser is an injected global var in the HTML head (a hacky fix until I get session/cookie stuff working properly)

```
  app.factory('UserService', function($http) {
    var pre;
    var sessionStatus;

    function init() {                   // Logged in  : Logged out             
      pre = appUser.user != undefined ? appUser.user  : { name: 'Logged out', uid: '0' };
      sessionStatus = pre.uid != "0"  ? true          : false;
    }

    function resetSession() { appUser = null; init(); }

    init();

    return {
      sessionStatus: function() { return sessionStatus; }, // update on change!

      logout: function() {
        $http.get("/logout").then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          resetSession();
        })
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, not asking you to change the requirements. But you should always  keep showing the Logout link better don't hide and show. Still if you want to achieve that functionality then use $timeout and may be set timeout interval to 5 secs. In that timeout code call a service that will check if session is valid or not and update the scope variable accordingly. But for every 5 secs u wud be calling your server so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of a `watch`, simply use a scoped `function` that returns the session status from the `service`.

```
$scope.sessionStatus = function() {
    return userService.sessionStatus();
};
```

Your Logout link would look as below:

```
<a ng-show="sessionStatus()" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a>
```

A stripped down Plunker for your functionality: http://plnkr.co/edit/u9mjQvdsvuSYTKMEfUwR?p=preview

Comment: Oh wow, a very elegant solution. Does Angular constantly run that function to check for changed values automatically or something?

Comment: Why is it that it doesn't work to just do `$scope.sessionStatus = userService.sessionStatus;`

Comment: How come the view won't refresh live if we change sessionStatus to : function(){return Date.now();}    http://plnkr.co/edit/rW4Q7OMSzqVrk9fSBBsE?p=preview. I would expect seeing the milliseconds ticking.

Answer (score 2):

Using a scoped function is cleaner and is the "correct" way to do it. Yet, for the sake of completeness you could also have fixed your watch:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return UserService.sessionStatus;
}, function() {
    $scope.sessionStatus = UserService.sessionStatus;
});
```

The first argument of the [$watch method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) takes a WatchExpression which can be a string or a method.

But again, $watch should not be used in controllers. Using scoped methods as suggested are cleaner and easier to test.